# Should I Cross-Up Combo Stunned Opponents for more Damage?

Tags: street-fighter-series

It has always been my understanding that in classic Street Fighter (ie. no focus attacks or extensive damage-scaling) and similar games that cross-up jump-ins (in addition to potentially forcing a defending opponent to guess which direction to block) usually enable an extra hit in combos for more damage.

Example:  In Capcom vs SNK 2, Ryu can combo from cross-up j. forward kick into close or crouching fierce and be close enough to finish with a Shoryuken.  He'd be too far to do this from a normal jump-in.

In spite of this, I have yet to see a match in which a stunned opponent eats up a cross-up combo.  Are there any significant obstacles discouraging it?  Is the timing any more strict to cross-up "deep" enough to reliably combo into the next attack on standing opponents (that are stunned), or is it just me?

If I just need more practice, are there any highly-regarded (particularly Ryu) players known to use this tactic?  If so, what footage is available of them doing this?  Do high-level players choose to forsake the additional damage of a cross-up combo to avoid error in high-pressure situations?

Comment: In SF4 series a level 3 focus attack into combo or raw ultra is usually the way to go for max damage.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the cross-up combo will lead to additional damage or some other concrete benefit over a normal jump-in combo (which, off the top of my head, should happen rarely, if ever), no, there's no particular reason to do that.

In general, the main benefit of cross-ups is that they force the opponent to block in the opposite direction. Ambiguous cross-ups are useful in that the opponent can't be certain which way to block at all. When the opponent is stunned, they can't block -- period -- so the primary benefit of a cross-up doesn't apply.

There are always exceptions, of course, depending on what game you're playing, what character you're playing, or what character your opponent is playing. There will even be variations based on the length of the combo that led up to the stun, as in many games, the internal damage scaling of a combo doesn't reset when an opponent is stunned, meaning that short-and-sweet combos may lead to more damage post-scaling than longer ones.

*As a general rule of thumb,* though, my personal experiences have led me to feel that you should focus on the shortest, highest-damage combo you have at your disposal, unless you know for certain that the optimal combo in that situation starts with a cross-up. This sort of thing is typically pretty easy to experiement with in training mode, so feel free to try different possibilities out.

Comment: A benefit from a cross up might be that you are in the corner and you want to get out and put your opponent in the corner at the same time.

Comment: True, but any strong jump-in combo should normally lead to some kind of knockdown, which should usually allow you to reposition yourself without needing to give up that extra damage.

Comment: Don't cross-up attacks cause your opponent to move towards you, enabling combos that normally only work in point-blank range? In Capcom vs SNK 2, Ryu can combo from cross-up forward kick into close or crouching fierce and be close enough to finish with a Shoryuken.  On a stunned opponent, the best combo I can land w/o meter is neutral j. roundhouse, cl./cr, fierce xx tatsu.

Comment: It probably is very particular to the game and character in question, but I don't doubt that such circumstances exist. I'll edit my answer to be clearer that there are always exceptions.

Comment: @PanicBomb I guess what I've been trying to ask is if there are any obstacles discouraging players from attempting cross-ups on stunned opponents, even if they do extra damage.  I'll update my question again to reflect this but I'm starting to wonder if I'm just looking to justify my combo incompetence.

You may want to type "@Orion751" in your responses as I wasn't emailed about your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the forest for the trees. Sure, a cross-up sometimes allows an extra hit. That is *not* the same thing as saying, "getting the specific extra hit that a cross-up enables always results in the most damage-optimised combo route". Sure, CvS2 Ryu can do j.MK cl.HP 236HP. Is that necessarily his hardest-hitting combo? And if it is, is it easier than other options?

You mention in a comment that your best post-stun combo is j.HK cl.HP 214HK. That combo is *way, way* easier to do than the cross-up one (I couldn't do the cross-up combo at all, and even with a *controller macro* I only hit it less than 10% of the time), and does virtually identical damage.

Being able to land an extra hit off of a cross-up is first of all not a universally-guaranteed feature, and even where it is, it is only one of dozens of factors that influence combos. Don't get hung up on one specific thing. The question isn't "how do I ensure I get a cross-up combo", the question is "how do I ensure I get *the best* combo".